# Linked List, C++ segmentation fault

Tags: c++, list, pointers, linked-list

I've been unable to complete my homework because I cannot seem to identify the source of this segmentation fault.

I am trying to add nodes to a linked list from a file.  I've run multiple tests and have narrowed the problem down quite a bit, but, I don't know what's actually creating the problem and therefore I create new problems when I try to change other details.

This is my second course, so, hopefully my code isn't so bad that it can't be helped.
Here's the add method:

```
    bool OrderedList::add (CustomerNode* newEntry)
{
if (newEntry != 0)
{
    CustomerNode * current;
    CustomerNode * previous = NULL;
    if(!head)
        head = newEntry;
    current = head;
  // initialize "current" & "previous" pointers for list traversal
   while(current && *newEntry < *current) // location not yet found (use short-circuit evaluation)
   {
    // move on to next location to check
    previous = current;
    current = current->getNext();
   }

  // insert node at found location (2 cases: at head or not at head)
  //if previous did not acquire a value, then the newEntry was
  //superior to the first in the list. 
  if(previous = NULL)
    head = newEntry;
  else
  {
    previous->setNext(newEntry); //Previous now needs to point to the newEntry
    newEntry->setNext(current); //and the newEntry points to the value stored in current.
  }
}
    return newEntry != 0;  // success or failure
    }
```

Okay, there is an overloaded operator< included in the program, outside testing does not indicate a problem with the operator, but I will include it as well:

```
    bool CustomerNode::operator< (const CustomerNode& op2) const
    {
       bool result = true;
       //Variable to carry & return result
       //Initialize to true, and then:
       if (strcmp(op2.lastName, lastName))
        result = false;

        return result;
       }
```

And here is the backtrace from gdb:

```
    #0  0x00401647 in CustomerNode::setNext(CustomerNode*) ()
    #1  0x00401860 in OrderedList::add(CustomerNode*) ()
    #2  0x004012b9 in _fu3___ZSt4cout ()
    #3  0x61007535 in _cygwin_exit_return () from /usr/bin/cygwin1.dll
    #4  0x00000001 in ?? ()
    #5  0x800280e8 in ?? ()
    #6  0x00000000 in ?? ()
```

This was the result of a lot of work of trying to correct a different segfault, and this one was much more surprising.  I have no idea how my setNext method is causing a problem, here it is:

```
void CustomerNode::setNext (CustomerNode* newNext)
{
    //set next to newNext being passed
    next = newNext;
    return;
}
```

Thanks in advance, I will be glad to post more of the code if it is necessary to identifying this problem.

Comment: Y u no `std::list` and `std::string`?

Comment: I think someone should edit this and replace "homework" with just "work", since "homework" is so deprecated on SO. Not to say decrepit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's

```
if(previous = NULL)
```

instead of

```
if(previous == NULL)
```

This sets `previous` to `NULL` and then enters the `else` branch:

```
previous->setNext(newEntry); //Previous now needs to point to the newEntry
newEntry->setNext(current);
```

resulting in undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you! I rewrote this method so many times... I was really hoping I had a manageable problem with this iteration.

Comment: Get into the habit of putting the constant first. That way if you accidentally drop the second equal-sign, the compiler will bark at you. Error C0042: "if(NULL=previous)" doesn't cut it. Also, NULL is old school. Today, we young guns use "nullptr".

Comment: @user1713830 if you're talking to user17... you should tag him in the comment, so he actually reads it. As for YODA conditions, it mostly depends on the coding guidlines and existing code. If 99% of existing code writes the constant as the second argument to operator ==, changing that and adopting your own style does more harm than good. Also, C++11 isn't spread enough yet to use nullptr instead of NULL.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(previous = NULL)
```

seems a bit dubious, as it will always evaluate to `false`.

You can avoid this kind of error in two main ways:

- be generous with `const`, sprinkle it almost everywhere you can, and
- when comparing with a value, put that value on the left hand side.

E.g., write

```
if( NULL = previous )
```

and get a compilation error instead of a crash or incorrect results.

Personally I don't do the value-on-the-left, because I never have this problem. I suspect in part because I'm pretty generous with `const`. But as a beginner, I think it's a good idea.

Comment: I don't do it that way either; possibly because of coming into C++ later in life and being brought up on sensible languages like Pascal and Ada where comparison is = and assignment is := :-) It can be a useful technique for avoiding such an easy mistake, but it doesn't aid readability due to the sense being reversed compared to how you would describe it in natural language (well, English). E.g. you would never say "if 30 is Fred" etc....

Answer (score 0):

You could do with posting all of your code, but the first obvious issue I can see is:

```
if(previous = NULL)
```

It's a very, very common mistake in C/C++/Java to use = when you mean ==.

Comment: Not that common. Plus, in Java, you'd get a compilation error because you can't treat references as booleans.

Comment: With respect to Java, yes, you're right. In C/C++ it's a very common fault and not that easy to spot, especially when you're just getting started in the language.